# How to make child class interchangeable with parent class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, variable-assignment

I am trying to do a C++ exercise, which consists of a test code (*main.cpp*) and a header file (*vcvec.h*). **The test code supposed to remain untouched**, whereas the included header file should satisfy the test code (this is what I have to write from scratch).

In this exercide I have to write an extension to the std::vector by inheritance. I managed to solve most parts of this exercise, now, I will attach below only the relevant part of the code.

main.cpp (test code)

```
#include <string>
#include "vcvec.h"

int main()
{
    version_controlled_vector<unsigned int> v;
    version_controlled_vector<std::string> a;

    v.push_back( 1 );
    a.push_back("C++");

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > histv = v;
}
```

vcvec.h

```
#ifndef VCVEC_H
#define VCVEC_H

#include <vector>

template<class T>
class version_controlled_vector : public std::vector<T>
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> history;
};

#endif // VCVEC_H
```

This code generates the following compile errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:52: error: conversion from ‘version_controlled_vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > > >’ requested
     std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a;
                                                    ^
main.cpp:13:44: error: conversion from ‘version_controlled_vector<unsigned int>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >’ requested
     std::vector<std::vector<int> > histv = v;
                                            ^
```

How can I assign an instance of version_controlled_vector to an std::vector type? The only solution I can think of, is an appropriate copy-constructor, but it should take place in the std::vector class, so it is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the options I can think of:

1. Provide a function that returns a reference to the private data.

   ```
   template<class T>
   class version_controlled_vector : public std::vector<T>
   {
       std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& getHistory() {return history;} const
     private:
       std::vector<std::vector<T>> history;
   };
   ```

   Then, in the client code, use:

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a.getHistory();
   ```
2. Provide an auto cast operator function

   ```
   template<class T>
   class version_controlled_vector : public std::vector<T>
   {
     public:
       operator std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& () {return history;} const
     private:
       std::vector<std::vector<T>> history;
   };
   ```

   Then, in the client code, use:

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a;
   ```
3. Make the data `public` so others can use directly (Not recommended)

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a.history;
   ```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

I am not sure how your files look like, but the following code, when put in one .cc file, compiles and builds for me.

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class version_controlled_vector : public std::vector<T>
{
   public:

      operator std::vector<std::vector<T> > const& () {return history;}

   private:

    std::vector<std::vector<T> > history;
};

#include <string>

int main()
{
    version_controlled_vector<unsigned int> v;
    version_controlled_vector<std::string> a;

    v.push_back( 1 );
    a.push_back("C++");

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > hista = a;
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > histv = v;
}
```

Comment: The 1st and 3rd options are not good for me, becouse main.cpp has to remain untouched. The 2nd one would be great, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @helmet91 there were couple of things I had to change to compile and build the code I added in my update. I added `public:` before the automatic cast operator in the class. In `main`, the last line had to be changed to use `unsigned int`.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, yes, it is `unsigned int`. And there was another mistake in my code. It looks like, it's not a good strategy to copy here only the relevant part of code. Thank you for your help!